# Regex - stop after first match with version numbers

Tags: python, regex, greedy

I have a regex that tries to match version numbers, however it is generating a lot of false positives.

`(\d{1,3}).*?(\d{1,3}).*?(\d{1,3})`

Is what I have so far, and this matches anything with 3 parts and 2 dots.
`1.2.333`
`11.2.3`

However it doesn't match things with 2 parts, and 1 dot,
`1.2`

It is also over greedy, so a line with multiple dots and parts, e.g **11.22.33** . **44.55.66**.77 it will match twice.

Im looking for a regex that will cover all scenarios,

`1.2`
`1.2.3`
and only match first instance of `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8`

[Pythex checker](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D).*%3F(%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D).*%3F(%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D)&test_string=%401.2.3.256.2%0Athis%40Basent.viewLi%0Atest%40test.com%0A1.2.333.2%0A11.2.3.2%0Astr%20%3D%20%222.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3%22%3B%0A%22%2F%0A%22%2Fproc%2Fself%2Ffd%2F%22%0A%22%2F%22%0A%22%2F11data%22%0A%22%2Fsys%2Fdevices%2Fsystem%2Fcpu%2F%22%0A0.0F%0A111.224.7.2.4%0A9.2.z-SNAPSHOT&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

EDIT:
I think `^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})(?:\.\d{1,3})?` will be as close as I can get it to cover the bulk of what I want so far
It still doesn't pick out the first 3 parts of a long list tho, I'll keep trying

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Perhaps like this `^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})+$` https://regex101.com/r/qTaFGZ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks, that doesn't pull out anything from ``1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8`` however, nor if it was something like ``1.2.z.FOO``

Comment: Post your answer in the answer box? ↓

Comment: @jerrythebum You have to enable multiline, see [pythex demo](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D)%2B%24&test_string=1.2%0A11.22.33%20.%2044.55.66.77%0A11.22.33%0A1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: @jerrythebum that's because of the `^` and `$` chars, they match the beginning and end of the string, that's why your 1.2.3.4... string does not match.

Comment: Can't you just switch off the global search and use `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}+){1,2}`? assuming you wanted to match `1.2.3` in `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8`

Comment: Why should the pattern match *anything at all* in `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8` or `1.2.z.FOO`, given that they clearly aren't version numbers (according to your definition, anyway)?

Comment: @ekhumoro it could be a really long version number? 3.12.41.12345, i would just want the first few digits. also 1.2.z.FOO, the 1.2 is the version number

Comment: @jerrythebum Then JvdV's pattern should solve it right using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) for example?

Comment: @jerrythebum So, you're not actually trying to match version numbers *per se*, but rather only specific parts of them. What should happen with cases like `1.2345` and `1.2.3456`? Your latest solution gives `1.234` and `1.2.345`, which doesn't seem right. It's also quite common to see dates used as versions numbers, like `2019.06.15` or `20180405.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
(?m)^.*?\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})?)\b
```

See [proof](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E.*%3F%5Cb(%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D)%3F)%5Cb&test_string=%401.2.3.256.2%0Athis%40Basent.viewLi%0Atest%40test.com%0A1.2.333.2%0A11.2.3.2%0Astr%20%3D%20%222.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3%22%3B%0A%22%2F%0A%22%2Fproc%2Fself%2Ffd%2F%22%0A%22%2F%22%0A%22%2F11data%22%0A%22%2Fsys%2Fdevices%2Fsystem%2Fcpu%2F%22%0A0.0F%0A111.224.7.2.4%0A9.2.z-SNAPSHOT&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Python code:

```py
re.findall(r'(?m)^.*?\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})?)\b', string)
```

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?m)                     set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) (case-
                           sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex you want is:

```
(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){1,2})(?:\.\d{1,3})*
```

The final subexpression, `(?:\.\d{1,3})*` is included to consume the rest of the input that would otherwise result in being matched when the `findall` scan resumed if this subexpression were not included, as in the case of `1.2.3 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8`.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pBrLpt/1/)

```
import re

s = 'abc 1.2 1.2.3 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8'

print(re.findall(r'(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){1,2})(?:\.\d{1,3})*', s))
```

Prints:

```
['1.2', '1.2.3', '1.2.3']
```

Alternatively, you can use a negative lookbehind:

```
((?<!\.)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){1,2})
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pBrLpt/2/)

```
import re

s = 'abc 1.2 1.2.3 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8'
print(re.findall(r'((?<!\.)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){1,2})', s))
```

Prints:

```
['1.2', '1.2.3', '1.2.3']
```

If you are using `search` instead of `findall`, the match is returned as Group 1.